# Prove that this set is a topology (closed rays)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a ray $[0; +\infty)$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is consist of $\emptyset, X$ and all open rays $(a; +\infty)$ where $a \ge 0$. In this case $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology.

But if it consisted of the closed rays $[a;+\infty)$ how to prove that it isn't topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\bigcup_{n=1} [1/n, \infty) = (0, \infty)$. This is not the empty set, all of $X$, or a closed ray.

Comment: Tanks, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$(a,\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}[a+\tfrac1n,\infty)$$